# What are these lock icons in my "computer"?

Tags: directory, lock

Does this look right to you?

[image: my "computer" directory]

I'm new to ubuntu, and I have feeling that it didn't used to be like this. I must have done something! How can I undo whatever I have done to it?

Edit: I log in like this: Turn on the computer. Wait..... voila

Edit2:

```
ali@ali-ubuntu-system:~$ ls -ld /{snap,media,initrd}
ls: cannot access '/initrd': No such file or directory
drwxr-xrwx 3 root root 4096 دسامب  6 04:28 /media
drwxr-xrwx 2 ali  ali  4096 ژوئن  30  2016 /snap
```

Comment: How did you log in the system? It is not normal.

Comment: Oops. That should have been `initrd.img`, so can you add the output of `ls -l /initrd.img`

Comment: @muru "initrd.img" is owned by root.

Comment: @kptlronyttcna good, but it should be a link and it doesn't seem to be one

Comment: @muru 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 دسامب  6 04:21 /initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic

Comment: i like the arabic in the filedescription. lovely :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lock icon indicates that you can't **write** to these files and folders. The location of "Computer" is `/`, and files and folders immediately in `/` are all usually owned by root and *don't* have write permissions for other users. Hence, the screenshot is mostly OK, except for the `snap` and `media` directories, and the `initrd` file. There's something wrong there, since none of them are writable by your user by default, and `initrd` is usually a symbolic link (like the `vmlinuz` file next to it).

Comment: I do not have locks on my system dirs.

Comment: @Pilot6 On 16.04?

Comment: Yes, on 16.04..

Comment: I didn't use to have them either. I think I ran "chmod 777 -R /" or something of that sort, Internet tells me to reinstall. :(

Comment: @kptlronyttcna yes, that's it - Nautilus doesn't show the lock icon if you don't have write permissions on the parent directory. Thank fully, it doesn't look like you ran `chmod -R` . You can just do `sudo chmod 755 /`. And since 1) `initrd.img` looks OK,  2) permissions of `/media` doesn't matter much, you can probably just do `sudo chown root:root /snap`

Comment: @muru so reinstall is not necessary?

Comment: @kptlronyttcna if it really were `chmod -R`, it would be, but it doesn't look like it, given only a couple of folders look different

Comment: @muru I think it really were -R. But I've closed it in middle because it was taking way too long to finish. Thanks anyway, I'm already half way reinstalled.

Answer (score 2):

The lock-symbol commonly denotes that your are logged in as a user who does not have the permissions to alter/edit/create/delete files downwards from the locked directory.

I can see that you are logged in as user "Ali". Was this the original user you created during the setup?

can you please supply the following information to us; open a terminal, type:

```
whoami
```

then

```
 sudo cat /etc/group
```

then

```
 cd /
```

then

```
ls -lh
```

..and supply us the output to this 4 commands?

the last one should return something like this:

```
user@box:/$ ls -lh
total 96K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Jan  3 15:32 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Jan 16 12:06 boot
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root 4.0K Dec 18 15:46 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root 4.3K Jan 24 14:41 dev
drwxr-xr-x 144 root root  12K Jan 24 14:41 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Dec 18 15:46 home
drwxr-xr-x  21 root root 4.0K Jan  3 15:25 lib
drwx------   2 root root  16K Dec 18 15:43 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Jan  4 14:59 media
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Jan  5 12:54 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Jan  4 16:39 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 189 root root    0 Jan 24 14:41 proc
drwx------   3 root root 4.0K Dec 18 15:48 root
drwxr-xr-x  27 root root  880 Jan 24 14:42 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  12K Jan  4 16:48 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Oct  6 19:49 snap
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Oct 12 21:42 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Jan 24 14:42 sys
drwxrwxrwt   9 root root 4.0K Jan 24 14:41 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root 4.0K Oct 12 21:50 usr
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root 4.0K Oct 12 21:57 var
```

As you can see, all directories are owned by user root and group root, but in most directories the 'normal' users have the rights to read and execute (r-x) e.g. in /boot: `drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Jan  3 15:32 bin` 
rwx (root) ... r-x (group) ... r-x (you == 'Ali')

Comment: They're all owned by root except 'snap' and 'vmlinuz'